# How to have more than one silverlight application in an ASP MVC project?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, expression-blend

I have an ASP MVC application which uses some silverlight applications in the View. By now, I hava a map, that, when a State is clicked, redirects to the related page. Now, I need a silverlight application in which state, with the state map and the location of the harbors on this state (you chose a state in the first map, than you get redirected to the chosen state, where you can select a harbor that will be highlighted in a table - not sure how I'll achieve that yet). Which type of class should I use to this new silverlight map of each state? Is it easy to do what I want? (I created an user controller class, but expression blend couldn't open it, don't know why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all your Silverlight controls are so similar in function that a single Silverlight application would do.

You can pickup the host-page url from within Silverlight and therefore use url parameters to determine what to display.

You also have options of communicating via Javascript to exposed methods on your Silverlight application and also the reverse (executing Javascript from the Silverlight app).

Not sure why you had problems with Blend without seeing the offending user control.

Hope this helps.